# Table ERROR:1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key?

Tags: mysql, sql, create-table

I am getting an error which I don't understand at all. I am trying to create a table and here is the code:

```
create table matricula.curso_estudiantes
(codigo varchar(8) NOT NULL,
studentid varchar(8) NOT NULL,
grade varchar(1) NOT NULL,
term numeric(5) NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY (codigo, studentid, term),
    FOREIGN KEY (codigo) 
            REFERENCES curso(codigo),
        FOREIGN KEY (studentid) 
            REFERENCES estudiantes(studentid));

insert  into matricula.curso_estudiantes values 
("COMP2120","X00101010","C",201010),
("COMP2315","X00101010","B",201030),
("COMP2120","X00121111","B",201030),
("COMP2315","X00121111","A",201030),
("COMP2120","X00121234","A",201130),
("COMP2900","X00101010","C",201110),
("COMP3850","X00101010","B",201110),
("COMP2900","X00121111","B",201130),
("COMP3850","X00121111","A",201130),
("COMP2315","X00121234","A",201130),
("COMP2400","X00101010","C",201210),
("MATH1500","X00101010","B",201210),
("COMP2400","X00121111","B",201230),
("MATH1500","X00121111","A",201230),
("COMP3850","X00121234","A",201230),
("MATH1500","X00121234","W",201230);
```

But I get this error instead:

> Error Code: 
>   constraint fails (`matricula`.`curso_estudiantes`, CONSTRAINT
>   `curso_estudiantes_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`studentid`) REFERENCES
>   `estudiantes` (`studentid`))

What seems to be the problem? It creates the table, BUT it gives me that problem and no records are inserted into the table. Which query resolves this? I am new to mySQL so I use a lot of references and examples form the professor.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the correct corresponding records in the `estudiantes` table?

A `FOREIGN KEY` means you need data in the referenced table, or the `INSERT` won't work.

To fix it, first create and populate your `estudiantes` and `curso` tables with valid data.

Comment: I have already created two tables. One for students called "estudiantes" and another for the courses "curso" They are filled with this info: http://i192.photobucket.com/albums/z30/FlameGhoul/Untitled.png http://i192.photobucket.com/albums/z30/FlameGhoul/Untitled1-1.png

Comment: Is the `studentid` column in the `estudiantes` table an index?

Comment: Also, try to separate the problem into pieces: creation of the table, and insertion of a record (try one first).